# rangeElement.getStartOffset() is always -1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to get the position of different rangeElements in a Google document. But the result is always -1.

What I did: I put every heading of my document into its own rangeElement, so that is has its own id. With this id I want to retrieve the content and position later on in a different function.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var paragraphs = doc.getBody().getParagraphs();
for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
if (paragraphs[i].getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
    var heading = paragraphs[i].asParagraph().getHeading();
    //get only headings
    if (heading == DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1) {
    var title = paragraphs[i].asParagraph().asText().getText();
    if (title != "") {
        //put every headings into its own range, so it has its own id
        var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange().addElement(paragraphs[i]);
        var id = doc.addNamedRange('toc', rangeBuilder.build()).getId();
        // check offset and text of the rangeElement
        var offset = doc.getNamedRangeById(id).getRange().getRangeElements()[0].getStartOffset();
        var text = doc.getNamedRangeById(id).getRange().getRangeElements()[0].getStartOffset();
    }
}
```

In this example the output of `text` is always the right heading. So the content of the rangeElement seems to be correct. But the output of `offset` is always -1.

What I want to do next is that:

```
doc.setCursor(doc.newPosition(rangeElement.getElement(), rangeElement.getStartOffset()));
```

But that does not work with a StartOffset of -1.

Comment: Are you thinking that `rangeElement.getStartOffset()` in `doc.setCursor(doc.newPosition(rangeElement.getElement(), rangeElement.getStartOffset()));` is the offset from the beginning of the bodyText.  I don't think it is.

Comment: @Cooper Well, honestly I really don't know. I read the reference again and again. And I tried many different ways in the code editor. But I really do not understand, how to get and store the position/offset of a specific paragraph or any rangeElement. The code example in the reference only shows, how to get the current cursor. But not, how to get the position of a specific element... Where can I find an example for that? I really have no idea, where to start.

Comment: When you do a search for text in the document with `findText()` it returns a rangeElement not an offset from the beginning of the text and if the returned rangeElement.isPartial() is true then the getStartOffset() provides an offset to the desired text from the beginning of the rangeElement.

Answer (score 1):

The Apps Scripts Documentation says: `getStartOffset()
Gets the position of the start of a partial range within the range element. If the element is a Text element and isPartial() returns true, the offset is the number of characters before the start of the range (that is, the index of the first character in the range); in any other case, this method returns -1.`

[Reference:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getStartOffset())

If you want to find the offset some piece of text in all of the documents text then try this.

```
function findTextOffset(s){
  var s=s || 'Monster';//debug default
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var text=doc.getBody().getText();
  var offset=text.indexOf(s);
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(Utilities.formatString('Find: %s Text: %s Offset: %s',s, text, offset));
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Text Offset');
}
```

Comment: Oh, okay. That does explain the -1. Because my rangeElement seems to contain the whole heading. But is there a way to retrieve the position/StartOffset of the whole heading somehow?

Comment: Take a look at the Class Position and the getOffset() method.  Read it carefully. [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position#getoffset)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry. Maybe I am to stupid, but I really do not get how this should work. Unfortunately the reference is very short and has no example how to retrieve the position from a given rangeElement. How can I find out, how to do this? I think, I just need an example for that. Google doesn't help me either...